How bad is this bathroom fan duct setup?
Bought a house about 9 months ago. Largely been good, but we've been having issues with the bathroom ventilation fan dripping moisture back down after longer/hotter showers, and generally not doing a good job venting the bathroom.
I just checked it out in the attic and want to know how bad this set is. We'll likely be doing big renovations in a year or so, so I'm looking to categorize this between "annoying but can live with it" to "will cause damage and needs immediate attention".
Sorry the picture is low quality. The setup seems to be the vent fan hooked up to thin-ish flexible ducting that ends completely open pointed vaguely in the direction of the attic ventilation fan.
My worries are basically:

In other setups I have seen, the ducting is much wider. Could this impact the effectiveness of the fan?
Will there be moisture buildup, since the ducting is just open in the attic?

If this needs fixing, would the best solution be to replace with wider flexible ducting and run it out of a roof vent?
I'm located in California, house was built in 1938 but the bathroom was renovated before the sale last year.


IT's bad...begin your renovations by correcting that mess.  You obviously know how wrong it is.

Yea I think I just needed someone to tell me that. Thanks.

I agree with RMDman. I doubt that works at all. Unless there is a fan in the bathroom and they are just using this for the exhaust outlet. Otherwise, there is no resistance to the air flowing from the attic and there would be resistance from the small flex tube. Consequently, hardly any air would be drawn through the flex by the roof fan.

There is a bathroom exhaust fan at the base of the duct which pushes some air out. The fan in the image is just the attic ventilation fan - it doesn't turn on with the bathroom fan. I'm not sure it turns on at all, but that might be a project for another day.

Since you're making modifications and you've got loads of space, consider using rigid ducting instead of flex. You'll get better air flow out of whatever fan is pushing air around.

This will result in bad condensation in the winter, and smells and stink year-round.  Fix so that it goes to a proper outside vent.
